# Ant command to compare string

Tags: ant

I am new to Ant could you please help me in below needs?

Am trying to compare a string on a file and append the new string and leave the existing string. Say my input is

Project=vinoth, raghu, ram

and i have a file called ram.properties. File looks like below

This is the file to understand Ant concept
Project=Vinoth, raghu

By comparing the input and the file only ram is missing on project values. 
I need to do the append the ram in project values of the file.I can write a simple loop like below to find but how can i append the values. 
Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A simple solution would be to run the build as follows: "ant -propertyfile ram.properties" Such an approach would not require any special logic in your build file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick try with ant using resources, you need ant >= 1.9.3 for the [if/unless feature](https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) :

```
<project
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>
<!-- Propertyfile containing the property to be compared against -->
<property file="ram.properties"/>

<!-- create macrodef for reuse -->
<macrodef name="stringcompare">
 <attribute name="property"/>
 <attribute name="string"/>
 <attribute name="update"/>

 <sequential>
  <resources id="property">
   <tokens>
    <stringtokenizer delims=", "/>
    <string value="${@{property}}"/>
   </tokens>
  </resources>

  <resources id="string">
   <tokens>
    <stringtokenizer delims=", "/>
    <string value="@{string}"/>
   </tokens>
  </resources>

  <difference id="diff">
   <resources refid="property"/>
   <resources refid="string"/>
  </difference>

  <echo> Diff ? => ${toString:diff}</echo>

  <replace file="@{update}" token="${@{property}}" value="${@{property}} ,${toString:diff}" unless:blank="${toString:diff}"/>

 </sequential>
</macrodef>

<stringcompare property="Project" string="vinoth, raghu, ram" update="ram.properties"/>

</project>
```

Note: the macrodef attribute property uses the propertyname (`property="Project"),` whereas the logic inside uses the propertyvalue `${@{property}}` !

**EDIT** after comment

> Required attribute property not set

means you called the macrodef without attribute property, f.e. :

```
<stringcompare string="vinoth, raghu, ram" update="ram.properties"/>
```

i've tried the snippet with a ram.properties like that :

> Project=vinoth, raghu

output:

```
[echo]  Diff ? => ram
```

ram.properties afterwards :

> Project=vinoth, raghu ,ram

Comment: Thanks for sharing Rebse. The string is getting added as delimiter as below. Vinoth, Ram, Raghu, URL;DEF;SAM. Difference Diff ? => values are written with delimiter ; . Could you please help?